# VBA code issue to combine multiple worksheets into a master sheet and refresh if master sheet is there

Tags: excel, vba, performance, ms-office

I am having an issue with my current code to combine worksheets into one master in order to create a pivot table. I think I am having an issue with where the code starts when combining the sheets. My spreadsheet is currently setup: Pivot Table | PivData | Month 1 | Month 2 | Month 3| Etc. The code will be ran through a button on the "Pivot Table" tab.

What the code does: Check's to see if there is already a sheet called "PivData" and replace data in that sheet if there is; if not, create new sheet and add the combined data. It also allows you to input a number for how many rows of headers.

What I want the code to do: Combine all tabs, using the same checks, to "PivData" starting at Month 1 and going right.

Each sheet has the exact same column headers and numbers etc. I believe that my code to copy the headers is pulling from the wrong sheet and I can't figure out how to change that.

Any help is very much appreciated as I am really struggling to figure this out.

```
Sub Combine()

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim TCount As Variant
    Dim xWs As Worksheet
    Dim check As Boolean
    
    On Error Resume Next

LInput:
    TCount = Application.InputBox("The number of title rows", "", "1")
    If TypeName(TCount) = "Boolean" Then Exit Sub
    If Not IsNumeric(TCount) Then
        MsgBox "Only can enter number"
        GoTo LInput
    End If
For Each xWs In Worksheets

    If xWs.Name Like "PivData" Then check = True: Exit For
    Next
    If check = True Then
        xWs.Cells.Clear
    GoTo Replace
    If Not xWs.Name = "PivData" Then
   GoTo AddSheet
    
    End If
    End If
    

AddSheet:

    Set xWs = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add(Sheets(1))
    xWs.Name = "PivData"
    Worksheets(2).Range("A1").EntireRow.Copy Destination:=xWs.Range("A1")
    For i = 3 To Worksheets.Count
        Worksheets(i).Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Offset(CInt(xTCount), 0).Copy _
               Destination:=xWs.Cells(xWs.UsedRange.Cells(xWs.UsedRange.Count).Row + 1, 1)
    Next
    
Exit Sub

Replace:

    xWs.Name = "PivData"
    Worksheets(2).Range("A1").EntireRow.Copy Destination:=xWs.Range("A1")
    For i = 2 To Worksheets.Count
        Worksheets(i).Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Offset(CInt(xTCount), 0).Copy _
               Destination:=xWs.Cells(xWs.UsedRange.Cells(xWs.UsedRange.Count).Row + 1, 1)
    Next
    
    
End Sub
```

Comment: First step: remove `On Error Resume Next` as that just hides potential errors. Next step: avoid `GoTo` as that creates spaghetti code.

Comment: Is there a better way to reference that section of code? Perhaps creating a separate sub and calling that sub?

Comment: Yes that would be a better approach.

Comment: Thank you for your advice @BigBen

Comment: You are adding `PivData` sheet as the first sheet and copying the header from `Sheet(2)` which presumably is `Pivot Table`, is that correct ? That means your layout is `PivData | Pivot Table | Month 1 | Month 2 |`